# What is the recommended method to analyse the structure of a HTML page/site?

Tags: map, files, assets

Recently, I have had to analyse and upgrade a web application.

I need to know the relationships and functions of each file including CSS and JS inside *each* page, as opposed to the whole website.

Thus, I would like to draw a "file map" to visually understand and easily track the file relationships.

What is the the best/recommended methodology to analyse and visualize the relationships including JS, CSS and so on?

*(I am not sure what to call this feature, so I have used "file map" at the moment)*

Comment: Can you rewrite this question NOT to ask for a tool recommendation and still get an answer that will help you? Recommendations are off-topic here. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks a lot, I have rewritten the question title and content. See if it shows a better match to the website.

Comment: I did what I can do. It is now up to the community. Cheers!!

Comment: @simongcc Can you explain what you mean by a visual "file map". Most developers use the Developer Tools inside of browsers like Chrome to view what's being requested, loaded, and rendered. Check out the Sources tab in Chrome's Developer Tools, which will show a hierarchy of what's been requested and from where. See this for a breakdown of: [Chrome's Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). If you're looking for a third-party tool, I'm afraid that would be off-topic for this site since that often leads to spam and self-promotion.

Comment: Are you using a particular CMS or framework at the moment? There might be something built in to that.

Comment: @dan Instead of hierarchy, I am looking for a way to understand the file relationship effectively. For example, if I display the relationship of css, js file in a spider map, I can digest it better than looking in a list(part of my personal preference). Because the web application I have to take care of consists of many libraries, custom js and css, I would like to visualize them in an intuitive way with comments to digest better. Or if you have a better method to digest or trace up an existing web application are also welcomed.

Comment: @Tim Malone, that's a CMS, and that is my company internally developed CMS in dot net, very old fashioned, less modern and hard to maintain. So I would like to give it a try to revamp bit by bit. Yet, they never have any docs, lost some sources. I wonder what I can understand it effectively. Because tracing back without a method, seems digging in something with no map, very time consuming.

Comment: @simongcc It sounds like you're looking for a flowchart tool, which can commonly show linked pages and resources, but typically not code references, which I would think would look really messy for anything but simple webpages. You might consider using a WYSIWYG editor (like Dreamweaver) where you can see and dissect CSS and JavaScript elements live on the page while in "Design" mode (by clicking to expose them further). That combined with Sources and Elements in the Developer Tools of browsers should help you to learn and understand how your webpages were constructed in a visual way.

Comment: @dan thanks for your insight, part of the page is work for your suggestion. I just look deeply the code that the CMS itself built on XSL and XML server side rendering together with frontend tools such as jQuery or custom written tools. And sometimes XSL include another XML to render. That's making me want to look for a systematic way to manage the relationships. Maybe there is no standard or usual way.

Comment: Thanks everyone's comment, sorry that I thought I was too busy and missed the community when I was immersed/being drowned to the work. It was a website that I need to help to revamp but I didn't have any information about it. And it was a custom ugly traditional structure with CSS and JS files everywhere. So I thought, if there is a map like a spider map or anything to tell me what is being linked to the html file might be useful. But because the company didn't provide and dreamweaver tools as well. So I was thinking using a programmatic way to do this such as using nodejs tools.